# Fundamental scientific publication in up conversion down conversion

Tags: reference-request, conversion

Prior to performing DSP on a signal and afterwards, up and down conversion of the same in order to transmit and receive the signal is important.

I would like to know if anyone knows a fundamental scientific publication of good clarity (preferably from a reputed publisher e.g. IEEE, ACM, Science Direct, SIGCOMM, etc) which introduces this concept. I understand that this publication will be an old one.

Comment: Nyquist 1928, prolly?

Comment: probably Shannon is better.  Nyquist wasn't particularly rigorous about it.

Comment: fair point, @robertbristow-johnson; though I find *Certain Topics in Telegraph Transmission Theory* to be pretty OK, the question really is which aspect David needs to show; for example, I'm currently reading a [paper](http://cyber.sci-hub.tw/MTAuMTEwOS90LWFpZWUuMTkwMC40NzY0MTQz/crehore1900.pdf) from 1900 which inadvertedly introduces BPSK; the discussions are pretty interesting, as one commenter is *so damn close* to pinpointing bandwidth limitations of reversing a sine's phase, it's really a thriller.

Comment: i think Shannon closed the circle with a reconstruction theorem and formula.  and, of course, relating this sampling and reconstruction theorem to his later discoveries in Information Theory.  i.e. the Sampling and Reconstruction theorems is needed to determine the information rate capacity of a channel, knowing bandwidth and S/N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Certain Topics in Telegraph Transmission Theory](http://astro.if.ufrgs.br/med/imagens/nyquist.pdf)* by Nyquist (1928) might be what you're looking for (**emphasis** mine):

> The following topics are discussed:
>
> 1. The required frequency band is directly proportional to the signaling speed.
> 2. **A repeated telegraph signal (of any length) may be considered as being made up of sinusoidal components.** When the amplitude and phase,
>      or real and imaginary parts, of these components are plotted as
>      ordinates with their frequencies as abscissas, and when the frequency
>      axis is divided into parts each being a frequency band of width
>      numerically equal to the speed of signaling, it is found that the
>      information conveyed in any band is substantially identical with that
>      conveyed in any other; and the bands may be said to be mutually
>      redundant.
> 3. The minimum band width required for unambiguous interpretation is substantially equal, numerically, to the speed of signaling and is
>      substantially independent of the number of current values employed.
> 4. A criterion of perfect transmission is selected; and a discussion is given of the characteristics which the received wave must have to
>      be nondistorting with the requirement that the frequency range should
>      not be greater than necessary.
> 5. Directions are sketched for specifying systems to meet this requirement.
> 6. Several alternative criteria of distortionless transmission are considered and a method for computing the corresponding transmission
>      characteristics of the circuit is explained and illustrated.
> 7. **An analysis is given of the carrier wave, and it is shown that the usual carrier telegraph requires twice as much frequency range as the
>      corresponding d-c. telegraph, other things being equal.**
> 8. **A discussion is given of two alternative methods for overcoming this inefficiency of carrier telegraphy, namely, the use of phase
>      discrimination and of a single sideband.**
> 9. After the d-c. and carrier waves have thus been analyzed a corresponding analysis is given of an arbitrary wave shape, including
>      these two as special cases. Calculations are given on the shaping of
>      the transmitted wave so as to make the received wave perfect.
> 10. A discussion is given of the dual aspect of the telegraph wave. The wave may be looked on either as a function of , requiring the
>       so-called steady-state method of treatment, or as a function of
>       requiring the so-called method of transients. **It is shown that the
>       steady-state theory can be made to yield the information necessary to
>       specify the characteristics of an ideal system.**
> 11. A discussion is given of the effect of interference and departures from ideal conditions.